# Не могу вывести на страничку PHP содержимое базы MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Написал код. При заходе на сайт, на странице выдает ошибку:

> Query error

Вот код:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Код</td>
<td>Фамилия</td>
<td>Имя</td>
<td>Отчество</td>
<td>Группа</td>
<td>Дисциплина</td>
<td>Форма контроля</td>
<td>Оценка</td>
<td>Дата</td>
<td>Преподователь</td>
</tr>
<?php
$db = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","") or die("Cannot connect db");
mysql_select_db ("site") or die("Cannot select site db");
$query = "SELECT  `Код` ,  `Фамилия` ,  `Имя` ,  `Отчество` ,  `Группа` ,  `Дисциплина` ,  `Форма контроля` ,  `Оценка` ,  `Дата` ,  `Преподаватель` FROM  `bebebe` ";
$result = mysql_query($query,$db) or die("Query error");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['Код'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Фамилия'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Имя'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Отчество'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Группа'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Дисциплина'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Форма контроля'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Оценка'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Дата'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Преподователь'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>

</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Плохая практика называть поля русскими словами. У Вас неправильно написан SELECT, я думаю Вы не указали из какой таблицы делать выборку. SELECT * FROM `table`. Так же после перечисления выбираемых полей после последнего запятая не ставится. Кстати Вы пользуетесь устаревшим методом http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php . Я рекомендую Вам переписать код с использованием PDO.